# I've messed up the heads of many people with my German, but how can I express this?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am wondering how one properly expresses, "to mess up somebody's head", in German. Let me give you two examples:

> 1. The constant propaganda took its toll and messed up his head.
> 2. Drugs really messed up his head/messed him up in the head.

I've seen "jemandem den Kopf verdrehen", but every dictionary seems to translate this as "to turn somebody's head", as in the context of a beautiful woman entering the room. So I am not 100% sure this is right, but I will go ahead and attempt a translation with this expression:

> 1. Der ständige Propaganda hat ein Tribut gefordert und ihm den Kopf verdreht.
> 2. Drogen haben ihm den Kopf verdreht.

Are these translation correct?

Comment: Shouldn't it read *heads* in the title (no apostrophe)? In my opinion *den Kopf verdrehen* is definitely temporary, while I assume that your second example intends to describe permanent damage. So more context would be helpful.

Comment: Drugs and alcohol can result in: Matschbirne

Answer (score 3):

*Jemandem den Kopf verdrehen* is idiomatic and **only** means a woman (less so: man) has messed with the mind of someone by flirting.

What you want to say is **vernebeln** or **zunebeln**. Instead of the whole head, the brain is often used.

> Ihr ständiges Gerede vom *Fahren auf Sicht* hat ihr selbst das Hirn vernebelt.
>
> Mit dem Shit war mehr als nur seine Wohnung zugenebelt.

Comment: "and only means a woman (less so: man) has messed with the mind of someone by flirting."
The emphasis on the _only_ is an exaggeration - while that's certainly by far the most common use, it is sometimes used to mean "draw someone's attention" or "confuse someone" in the general sense.

Comment: Please give an example of another use.

Answer (score 1):

In der Tat! Den Kopf verdrehen Frauen Männern. Allenfalls anatomisch könnte ich mir noch vorstellen, dass ein Tennisspieler bei einer extremen Rückhand sich den Kopf verdreht hat, und jetzt zur Behandlung muss.

"Den Kopf vernebelt" ist eine andere Metapher, aber dafür, was Propaganda und Drogen betrifft, die gängige:

```
Die (fem.) ständige Propaganda hat ihren Tribut gefordert und ihm den Kopf vernebelt.

Drogen haben ihm den Kopf vernebelt.
```

Durch Propaganda kann man einen politischen Gegner insgesamt umdrehen, bzw. in Spionagefilmen spricht man davon, ein Agent sei umgedreht worden, aber eben nicht nur der Kopf, sondern die Person.

Comment: Zu deinem ersten Satz: Es funktioniert auch andersrum.

Comment: fem. == feministische Propaganda? Ernsthaft?

Comment: @Thomas: Nein. Nicht, wie in der Frage "Der ständige Propaganda" sondern "Die ständige Propaganda"; fem. := femininum, weiblich.

Comment: @tofro: In der Theorie, ja. Und in der fem. Propaganda. ;)